# Posting news feeds in facebook

Tags: php, facebook, api

```
$config = array(
 'appId'  => 'yyyyyyyyyy',
 'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
 'cookie' => true,
 'domain' => true
);

$facebook_client = new Facebook($config);

//Grab the user's session
$session = $facebook_client->getSession();

/*If session does not exist, the user is not loggedin or hasn't added the app
so redirect them to the authorize page.*/
if(!$session){
 $text = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\ntop.location.href = \"$oauth_url\";\n</script>";
 echo $text;
 exit;
}
$access_token = $access['access_token'];
$params = array('access_token' => $access_token);
try{
$me = $facebook_client->api('/me',$params);
$feed_params = array();
$feed_params['message'] = "Hello world";
$feed_params['link'] = "http://apps.facebook.com/jagdish/";
$feed_params['name'] = "jag";
$feed_params['caption'] = "Trying to post from application";
$feed_params['description'] = "From jag";
$feed_params['access_token'] = $access_token;
$id = me['id'];
$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/','post',$feed_params);
}
catch(FacebookApiException $e)
{
    error_log($e);
}
```

This is my code. When i executed it, got an exception saying

```
com.caucho.quercus.QuercusException: com.caucho.quercus.QuercusErrorException: /base/data/home/apps/fbookworkshop/version1.349114876107177725/index.php:49: Fatal Error: Method call 'api' is not allowed for a null value.
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: afff please put your code in a code block!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are mixing 3 (or more) tutorials together!!

**Issues in your code:**
*The first issue:*

```
$text = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\ntop.location.href = \"$oauth_url\";\n</script>";
```

In this line:

1. Where did you set the `$oauth_url`?
2. Also no need for the `\n`

*The second issue* (mentioned by @fazo).

*The third issue*, **NO NEED** for the `access_token` all together if there's a valid session! so don't set it or use it in any of your requests as long as you are using `/me`.

*The fourth issue:*

```
$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/','post',$feed_params);
```

Here you are using the code from another tutorial, since you are using `$facebook` var instead of `$facebook_client`

Comment: Thanks to ifaour. I used $facebook instead of $facebook_client and thats why it wasn't working. Now fixed it. :)

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$access_token = $access['access_token'];
```

to

```
$access_token = $session['access_token'];
```

and tell us what happened

**UPDATE:**

looks like you can't use /me

https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/issues/closed#issue/294

Comment: I changed $access_token = $access['access_token']; to $access_token = $session['access_token']; But still getting the same exception.